# Jquery ajax call will not reach succes function

Tags: ajax, jquery, spring-mvc, controller

Pulling out my hair. Countless hours trying to get ajax call to work...

Jquery:

```
function doAjaxPost(episode_id) {

    alert("cc");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/yay/episodes/remove",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            episode_id : episode_id
        }), 
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(){

            alert("o");
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.error(errorThrown);
        }
    });
};
```

Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/episodes/remove", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public void removeEpisodeFromList(@RequestBody String episode_id) {

        System.out.println("Episode_id : " + episode_id);       
    }
```

And I call the function from:

```
<a href = "#" onclick = "doAjaxPost(${episode.episode_pk});"> MARK AS WATCHED </a>
```

It reaches the controller where the correct thing is printed out.
But then FireBug just says "SyntaxError {}" and success function alert is never called.

Comment: most likely `${episode.episode_pk}` is inserting something into your html that isn't valid in that location.

Comment: Don't you need to return something from your controller method rather than using void?

Comment: It is just an integer. Altering it out shows only int. And I don't need to return anything from the controller.

Comment: use "View Source" in your browser and find that anchor tag.

Comment: <a href = "#" onclick = "doAjaxPost(615);">       MARK AS WATCHED </a>

Answer (score 1):

It probably won't affect the data being passed in, but you really don't need the JSON.stringify action on your data parameter.  See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#example-0

Also, if you are trying to get JSON back from your spring MVC controller, you need to use the @ResponseBody annotation.  This will instruct Spring to not try to render out the template.  I actually wrote a blog post about getting JSON back from a spring MVC application a little while back that may help.

The section titled "Mapping the response body with the @ResponseBody annotation" [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) can give you more information

Also, the success() function is depreciated.  The done() function should be used now.  More information on that can be seen at the jquery url above.

Hope this helps!

http://benashby.com/spring/response-body-annotation

Comment: If what I posted helped you an upvote and check as answered would be helpful to me :)  Thanks!